# Making Python RegEx use variables for string expressions

Tags: python, regex, string, variables, syntax

I have a .csv file with the regular expression patterns that I want to match as well as the replacement patterns that I want. Some are extremely simple, such as "." -> "" or "," -> "".

When I run the following code, however, it doesn't seem to recognize the variables and the pattern is never matched.

```
                f = open('normalize_patterns.csv', 'rU')
                c = csv.DictReader(f)
                for row in c:
                    v = re.sub(row['Pattern'],row['Replacement'],v)
```

Afterwards, v is never changed and I can't seem to find out why. When I run the simple case of

```
                v = re.sub("\.", "", v)
                v = re.sub(",", "", v)
```

however, all the periods and commas are removed. Any help on the issue would be amazing. Thank you in advance! (I am pretty sure that the .csv file is formatted correctly, I've run it with just the "." and "" case and it still does not work for a certain reason)

Edit:
Here are the outputs of printing row. (Thanks David!)

```
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)&'", 'ID': '1', 'Replacement': "'and'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\bAssoc\\b\\.?'", 'ID': '2', 'Replacement': "'Association'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\bInc\\b\\.?'", 'ID': '3', 'Replacement': "'Inc.'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\b(L\\.?){2}P\\.?'", 'ID': '4', 'Replacement': "''"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\bUniv\\b\\.?'", 'ID': '5', 'Replacement': "'University'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\bCorp\\b\\.?'", 'ID': '6', 'Replacement': "'Corporation'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\bAssn\\b\\.?'", 'ID': '7', 'Replacement': "'Association'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\bUnivesity\\b'", 'ID': '8', 'Replacement': "'University'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\bIntl\\b\\.?'", 'ID': '9', 'Replacement': "'International'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\bInst\\b\\.?'", 'ID': '10', 'Replacement': "'Institute'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)L\\.L\\.C\\.'", 'ID': '11', 'Replacement': "'LLC'"} 
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)Chtd'", 'ID': '12', 'Replacement': "'Chartered'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)Mfg\\b\\.?'", 'ID': '13', 'Replacement': "'Manufacturing'"}
{'Pattern': 'r"Nat\'l"', 'ID': '14', 'Replacement': "'National'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)Flordia'", 'ID': '15', 'Replacement': "'Florida'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\bLtd\\b\\.?'", 'ID': '16', 'Replacement': "'Ltd.'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\bCo\\b\\.?'", 'ID': '17', 'Replacement': "'Company'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\bDept\\b\\.?i\\'", 'ID': '18', 'Replacement': "'Department'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)Califronia'", 'ID': '19', 'Replacement': "'California'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\bJohn\\bHopkins\\b'", 'ID': '20', 'Replacement': "'Johns Hopkins'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\bOrg\\b\\.?'", 'ID': '21', 'Replacement': "'Organization'"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)^[T]he\\s'", 'ID': '22', 'Replacement': "''"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\bAuth\\b\\.?'", 'ID': '23', 'Replacement': "'Authority'"}
{'Pattern': "r'.'", 'ID': '24', 'Replacement': "''"}
{'Pattern': "r','", 'ID': '25', 'Replacement': "''"}
{'Pattern': "r'(?i)\\s+'", 'ID': '0', 'Replacement': "''"}
```

And here are a few lines of the csv file (Opened in TextMate)

```
0,r'(?i)\s+',''
1,r'(?i)&','and'
2,r'(?i)\bAssoc\b\.?','Association'
3,r'(?i)\bInc\b\.?','Inc.'
```

Comment: Could you post an exact test-case input?

Comment: There are two issues with your code. First there is an extra `}`, second I think you mean `row["Replacement"]` instead of `row[replacement]`.

Comment: Seconding, CPP, to help you we _really_ need to know what the values of `row['Pattern']`, `row['Replacement']`, and `v` are.

Comment: Sorry! Yeah I meant row["Replacement"], typo (I had a string formatted "%(replacement)s" % {"replacement": row["Replacement"]} before but I just took it out for readability). (Fixed Now)

Comment: @Kevin: Don't post the input in a comment, add it to the original post by editing.

Comment: @Jim: Thanks! It's up there now

Comment: Could you `print row` inside the loop, then show the output of that? eg, `for row in c: print "    ", row`, then paste the output into the question?

Comment: Also, could you paste a line or two of your CSV file here?

Comment: @Kevin: I meant an actual sample of the input file, formatted as code (use the `{}` button), not your interpretation of it.  We need to see the literal input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that your pattern values are not actually the regex pattern you want, your regex pattern is wrapped in an additional string.

For example, in your dictionary you have the value `"r'.'"`, which you are using as a pattern.  You code will run `re.sub("r'.'", "", v)`, which probably isn't what you want:

```
>>> re.sub("r'.'", "", "This . won't match")
"This . won't match"
>>> re.sub("r'.'", "", "This r'x' will match")
'This  will match'
```

To fix this you should go back to where you are adding the regex to the dictionary and stop doing whatever is causing the string wrapping.  It might be something like `row['Pattern'] = repr(regex)`.

If you need to keep the dictionary the same for reason then be very careful with `eval`, if the strings are coming from an untrusted source then `eval` is a big security risk.  Use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead.

Comment: Definitely makes sense, eval made some errors regarding '\.' since the backslash is read as a literal is translated to '\\.' Thanks Andrew!

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the r'' around the pattern, it will work.

So the pattern that matches . should be as simple as '\.' instead of "r'\.'"

The problem is r in your pattern is taken as a literal r instead of it raw string meaning.

So you can also try:
    v=re.sub(eval(row['Pattern']), row['Replacement'], v)

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem to have done anything: I think the r is optional with python regex.

Comment: r means raw string. if you have r in the value of the pattern, it will be a literal r instead of telling python what follows is a raw string.

Comment: So for the inputs outputs I've changed to:
0,'(?i)\s+',''
1,'(?i)&','and'
2,'(?i)\bAssoc\b\.?','Association'
Was this what you meant by remove the 'r' character?

Comment: See my edit. You can put row['Pattern'] into an eval to make use of the r prefix